# insertAdjacentHTML can't read property of null

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

The following error keeps repeating... I just want explanation what is wrong here and some hint

#### error

```
script.js:20 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null
at renderHTML (script.js:20)
at XMLHttpRequest.ourRequest.onload (script.js:13)
```

#### javascript

```
var animalContainer=_('animal-info');
function _(id){

    return document.getElementById(id);

}

_('btn').addEventListener("click",function(){
    var ourRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequest.open('GET','test.json');
    ourRequest.onload=function(){
        var ourData=JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);
        renderHTML(ourData);
        console.log(ourData[0]);
    };
ourRequest.send();
});

function renderHTML(data){
     animalContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','testing 123');
}
```

#### index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>


    <button id ="btn">Submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>


<div id="animal-info"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place your script tag just before the closing tag of `body` Or use a load event instead.

Comment: worked! thanks a lot

Comment: Aliasing common built in functions like `getElementById` with `_` is confusing and prevents you from implementing frameworks properly/at all. The few bytes you save will not make your script run faster yet make it a hell to maintain, especially for other people.

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the **animalContainer** variable inside the **renderHTML()** function, or pass it as an argument.